# Typescript const reusing property values to define new properties

Tags: typescript

Is there a way I can reuse the property value defined in an const object in Typescript to define other new properties in the same object?

Something like this:

```
const TEST = {
  "a1": "world",
  "a2": "hello",
  "a3": this.a1
};
```

console.log(TEST.a3); logs undefined right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because `TEST` isn't defined yet then.
For example, if you try this:

```
const TEST = {
  "a1": "world",
  "a2": "hello",
  "a3": TEST["a3"]
};
```

You'll get:

> Error: Block-scoped variable 'TEST' used before its declaration

You can do this:

```
const TEST = {
  "a1": "world",
  "a2": "hello"
} as { a1: string, a2: string, a3: string };

TEST.a3 = TEST.a1;
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20TEST%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%22a1%22%3A%20%22world%22%2C%0A%20%20%22a2%22%3A%20%22hello%22%0A%7D%20as%20%7B%20a1%3A%20string%2C%20a2%3A%20string%2C%20a3%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0A%0ATEST.a3%20%3D%20TEST.a1%3B))